# Comparison of exponential growth with power

Tags: exponential-function

Please, help me.

> Consider the functions $f$ and $g$: $f(x)=2^x$ and $g(x)=x^{(\sqrt{15})}$.
>   Set the minor whole value of $x$ that satisfies the conditions: $f(x)-g(x)>10^6$.

So, I don't know how I can simplify this $x^{\sqrt{15}}$ in a way that I can work with the other two terms of the inequality.

I would be glad if any of you guys just gave me a hint.

Comment: Are you looking for integer $x$ such that $2^x>10^6+x^{\sqrt{15}}$? Can you increase $15$ to $16$ and then work with $x^4$?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea of how I can do that.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. What is 'minor whole value of $x$'? Your 'set' means 'find'? In general $2^x$ grows much faster than $x^n$.

Comment: The minor whole is like 1, 2, 3... And by "set" I mean "find".

Comment: English is not my first language...

Comment: Your answer is here https://goo.gl/ilGjcb. But you if you are interested in exploring relationship between exponential and power growth, see this https://goo.gl/ZNuXb8